# Añadir items a un pila en Python

Tags: python, tkinter, pilas

Necesito añadir un cantidad de información requerida en un programa la cual me ubique tal información en una estructura de pilas, para ello estoy usando una intefaz gráfica con Tkinter la cual recibe los datos tales como, código, nombre y teléfono. Tenía la duda de como puedo hacer esto un grupo único de datos si los recibo por separado, es decir, recibo el código en un TextField, asimismo el nombre y el télefono, siendo el código un tipo de llave primaria la cual asocie ese número (El Código) tanto al nombre como al télefono.

Este es el código:

```
def validate(S):
    try:
        float(S)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        messagebox.showerror(message="Datos erroneos, únicamente números.", title="ERROR")
        return False

tk.Label(master, text="Código:").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(master, text="Nombre:").grid(row=1)
tk.Label(master, text="Télefono:").grid(row=2)

e1 = tk.Entry(master, validate="key", validatecommand=(master.register(validate), '%S'))
e2 = tk.Entry(master, )
e3 = tk.Entry(master, )

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)

tk.Button(master, text='Añadir',command=show_entry_fields).place(x=75,y=70)
```

Coloco aquí el método validate para confirmar que el código es unicamente númerico, cosa que también deseo hacer para el nombre(Recibiendo unicamente String). Actualmente estoy buscando la manera de añadir estos items recibidos a una pila como dije anteriormente cada uno como un grupo unico de datos.

Comment: Hola SERGIO ANDRES VALDERRAMA VELEZ , para poder ayudarte necesitamos ver tu código, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y lo agregues como texto, de está forma evitarás recibir votos negativos y obtendrás la respuesta más rápido.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario Marce, fijandome un poco cometí un error en mi código, intentaré añadirlo lo antes posible a la pregunta :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear un diccionario en el que la clave sea el código y los valores sean el nombre y el número de teléfono, luego cada vez que agregues un nuevo elemento a la pila, puedes agregar el diccionario correspondiente a la pila. Algo así:

```
stack = []

def show_entry_fields():
    codigo = e1.get()
    nombre = e2.get()
    telefono = e3.get()
    datos = {codigo: (nombre, telefono)}
    stack.append(datos)
    print(stack)
```

Y si deseas obtener los datos de la pila puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
def obtener_datos(stack, codigo):
    for datos in stack:
        if codigo in datos:
            nombre, telefono = datos[codigo]
            return nombre, telefono
    return None, None

nombre, telefono = obtener_datos(stack, codigo_buscado)
if nombre:
    print(f"Nombre: {nombre}, Teléfono: {telefono}")
else:
    print("No se encontraron datos para ese código")
```

Ahora tu código completo sería algo así, además hay una pequeña incongruencia en el uso de los métodos place y grid. La función place se usa para ubicar los widgets en una posición específica en la ventana, mientras que grid se usa para organizarlos en una cuadrícula.
En este caso, estás utilizando place para crear el botón, pero los labels y las entradas de texto están siendo ubicados en una cuadrícula con grid. Esto puede causar problemas en la visualización.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

stack = []

def validate(S):
    try:
        float(S)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        messagebox.showerror(message="Datos erróneos, únicamente números.", title="ERROR")
        return False

def show_entry_fields():
    codigo = e1.get()
    nombre = e2.get()
    telefono = e3.get()
    datos = {codigo: (nombre, telefono)}
    stack.append(datos)
    print(stack)

def obtener_datos(stack, codigo):
    for datos in stack:
        if codigo in datos:
            nombre, telefono = datos[codigo]
            return nombre, telefono
    return None, None

master = tk.Tk()
master.title("Añadir información")

tk.Label(master, text="Código:").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(master, text="Nombre:").grid(row=1)
tk.Label(master, text="Télefono:").grid(row=2)

e1 = tk.Entry(master, validate="key", validatecommand=(master.register(validate), '%S'))
e2 = tk.Entry(master)
e3 = tk.Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)

tk.Button(master, text='Añadir', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, column=0)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar ; [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!